Flutter RenderBox exception not being caught
I have the following function, which returns the height of an element associated with the global key kMovingText :
  double getMovingBoxHeight() {
    try {
      RenderBox textbox =
          kMovingText.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      return textbox.size.height;
    } on Exception catch (_) {
      return 0;
    }
  }

The element associated with the key is is an OverlayEntry, which is created within a function showOverlay().
This function is called within initState as follows:
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  showOverlay();
});

The function works and returns the correct value. However, the first time it is called, because I think the overlay has not yet been created, an error (red background, yellow text), for a split second flashes on part of the screen.
In the debug console:
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building MyTestOverlayWidget(dirty, state: _MyTestOverlayWidgetState#e8b10):
Null check operator used on a null value
...

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderParagraph#47e8e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2165 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was:
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ 

Running with debug, it is evident that
kMovingText.currentContext!

returns null
While the error also appears in the console and terminal when running on a real device, only when running on the iPhone simulator does the error flash up on the app.
Two questions:
First, why is the exception not being caught by the surrounding try-catch block.
Second, is there a better way to handle this than by catching the exception the first time the code is run.
Thanks

In simpler terms, the try-catch block catches exceptions thrown within your code that's why that exception as you can see was caught by the widgets library on the flutter side. When and where did you call the function getMovingBoxHeight? Calling getMovingBoxHeight before showing the overlayEntry might be helpful.
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      boxHeight = await getMovingBoxHeight();
      showOverlay();
    });
  }

